# Driver causing sleep wake failure

Tags: macos, debugging, kernel, iokit, xnu

As a security research I am writing a custom *IOKit* driver. The driver registers itself through the power plane to drivers it depends on. (USB services). The `setPowerState` function is being called and the driver shutdown itself correctly.

Problem is, randomly it causes sleep wake failures issues and the machine restarts itself. Actually the reset occurs during a wakeup of the machine after it entered sleep (trying to hibernate apparently)

Question is, how can I debug or solve it? I am using a firewire kernel debugging to view what is going on, but the debugger and the breakpoints are causing delays in the sleep timing mechanism and everything is a mess.

Data in the internet is pretty weak regarding this issue but full of complains about OSX machines causing sleep wake failures in a clean machines.

I am testing it on various machines and kernel versions and it is  persistent.

Any clue will help.

EDIT: Additional code

```
enum
{
    kOffPowerState, kStandbyPowerState, kIdlePowertState, kOnPowerState, kNumPowerStates
};

static IOPMPowerState gPowerStates[kNumPowerStates]   =
{
    //kOffPowerState
    {kIOPMPowerStateVersion1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},

    //kStandbyPowerState
    {kIOPMPowerStateVersion1, kIOPMPowerOn, kIOPMPowerOn, kIOPMPowerOn, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},

    //kIdlePowerState
    {kIOPMPowerStateVersion1, kIOPMPowerOn, kIOPMPowerOn, kIOPMPowerOn, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},

    //kOnPowerState
    {kIOPMPowerStateVersion1, kIOPMPowerOn | kIOPMDeviceUsable, kIOPMPowerOn, kIOPMPowerOn, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
};

bool driver::start(IOService* provider)
{
    IOLog("driver::start\n");

    if (IOService::start(provider) == false)
        return false; 

   PMinit();

   provider->joinPMtree(this);    
   makeUsable();
   changePowerStateTo(0);
   registerPowerDriver(this, gPowerStates, kNumPowerStates);
   registerService();
   return true;
}

IOReturn driver::setPowerState (unsigned long whichState, IOService * whatDevice)
{
    IOLog("driver::setPowerState (%lu)\n", whichState);

    if (whichState == 0)
        IOLog("driver: shutdown (%lu)\n", whichState);

    return kIOPMAckImplied;
}
```

Comment: are you sure that the machine isnt kernel panicking? also maybe the SMC is programmed in such a way that a long delay in the wake makes it think the machine is frozen (and maybe it is frozen due to an infinite loop in your driver or something).

Comment: Can you reduce the problem to a super minimal kext? This doesn't seem like the kind of thing we can help you debug without any code.

Answer (score 1):

An unreleased reference to `IOService` caused a dead lock in the sleep sequence.

We used the following code to obtain `IOService` pointers.

```
mach_timespec time;
time.tv_sec = 0;
time.tv_nsec = 1000;
IOService* service = IOService::waitForService(IOService::serviceMatching(class_name, NULL), &time);
return service;
```

both `IOService::serviceMatching` and `IOService::waitForService` increase reference counters.

Changed to the following example code:

```
OSDictionary *dict = IOService::serviceMatching(class_name, NULL);

if (dict == NULL)
    return NULL;

IOService* service = IOService::waitForMatchingService(dict, 1000);

dict->release();

return service;
```

`IOService::waitForMatchingService` *does not* increase a reference counter and we release the `OSDictionary` pointer.

Comment: I understand it's a quite old post, but I encountered exactly the same problem. I am learning and unfortunately do not understand your answer. Could you please explain, do you mean that I should not use IOService* provider in the IOService::start, but your (or similar) code instead? Do I need to use it somewhere else?
Thank you!